# Scene2D's ClickListener with custom Actor

Tags: libgdx, scene2d, clicklistener

On Scene2D, f I have a custom actor, how do I make my ClickListener to be able to refer to that 'customActor's fields and methods? Since for example the enter method goes:

```
public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) { ... }
```

The thing is that that `fromActor` Actor reference can't see the fields that I want to modify in my `CustomActor`... I'm aware that I could do something along:

```
public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {       
    if(fromActor instanceof CustomActor) {
        CustomActor actor = (CustomActor)fromActor;
    }
}
```

But to me that doesn't feel right, there's gotta be a more efficient way; so if you know of one, please let me know :D

Comment: If all your instances of this actor use the same type of click listener, you can define the click listener as an inner class of the actor, or you can instantiate it as an anonymous class from the actor's constructor. If not, assign your actor to a member variable in the same class as your click listener is defined, and refer to that member variable in the click listener's methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class where you are instantiating this click listener, add an inner class that looks like this:

```
class CustomListener extends ClickListener {

    private final CustomActor yourActor;

    public CustomListener(CustomActor yourActor) {
        this.yourActor = yourActor;
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        this.yourActor.accessTheFieldYouWant;
    }
}
```

You can of course override any methods that you need, not just `enter`.

Then use it like this

```
yourActor.addListener(new CustomListener(yourActor) {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
    }
});
```

That's how I normally set things up, but you can put the custom listener class code wherever you want, or have a separate class file for it and import it.

Comment: But can I not have only 1 listener for the same type of actors? 'same type' being multiple actors of the same class.